# Search Stored Procedures, Functions & Triggers for Keyword

Tags: sql-server-2008, search, stored-procedures, triggers, user-defined-functions

I'm getting the error:

```
Invalid column name 'Reserved'
```

I'm not sure where in my database code this is, and have 100s of stored procedures, functions & triggers which I would have to manually look through to find this reference to an unknown column.

Is there a way of quickly searching for which objects contain this keyword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT o.name, t.TABLE_NAME, c.text 
  FROM syscomments c 
  JOIN sysobjects o 
    ON c.id = o.id
  JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables t
    ON  c.text LIKE '%reserved%'
```

Or if you looking for tables with a column called Reserved you do:

```
select o.name 
from sys.objects o 
inner join sys.columns c 
on o.object_id = c.object_id
where o.type = 'u' and c.name = 'Reserved'
```

If you want to filter your search on certain type of objects such as procedures, views, or tables you can do it adding 'p' for stored procedures, 'v' for views, 'u' for user defined tables, 'tr' for triggers ex:

```
AND o.type = 'p'
```

Comment: Valid for ***`views, stored procedures, user defined tables, triggers`***, and for _**functions, Constraints,  Rules, Defaults**_ ?

Comment: How filter a column name like ***[NumeroTotal]*** eg: `([NumeroUsadas]<=[NumeroTotal] AND [NumeroTotal]>=(0))`. For me this `c.text LIKE '%[NumeroTotal]%'` not works, neither `'%[[NumeroTotal]]%'`

Comment: `JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables t` ***without*** `on t.xxx = c.yyy` ?  only `ON c.text` ?
 IMHO Better: `SELECT o.name, o.type, o.xtype, c.text 
, USER_NAME(o.uid) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(c.id) AS 'Object name'
  FROM syscomments c 
  JOIN sysobjects o 
    ON c.id = o.id
   where c.text LIKE '%NumeroTotal%' or c.text LIKE '%NumeroUsadas%'`

Comment: _Just be aware that the syscomments table stores the values in 8000-character chunks, so if you are unlucky enough to have the text you're searching for split across one of these boundaries, you won't find it with this method_ via http://stackoverflow.com/a/4222372/206730

Answer (score 0):

Using [**RedGate's SQL Search**](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) extension might be able to help as well